# Proof of error propagation formula?

Tags: numerical-methods

In my course we have stated and used the error propagation formula:

$$|y-y_0|\approx|f^\prime(x)|\cdot|x-x_0|$$

But it was presented with no proof and I wonder if you can help me understand the formula holds?

Comment: You don't recognize the first few terms of the Taylor expansion? :)

Comment: @J.M. OK but to me the first two terms of Taylor expansion is f(a)+f'(a)(x-a)/2. I'm working on how the two common Taylor expansions are equivalent.

Comment: @NickRosencrantz: The $2$ at the bottom shouldn't be there. The **next** term is $\frac{f''(a)}{2!}(x-a)^2$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Yes, exactly. I was wrong from memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possibly the best way to understand it is via the [mean value theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem): $$f(x)-f(x_0)=f'(c)\cdot(x-x_0)$$ for some $c$ between $x_0$ and $x$. If $f'$ is continuous, $f'(c)$ can be expected to be close to $f'(x)$ or $f'(x_0)$ when $\lvert x-x_0\rvert$ is small enough.

Comment: Thank you. It's somewhat more info for me to go on than just the Taylor expansion again.